# Problems with template type deduction with a C++ std::function argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

In C++20 I'm trying to pass a function object, either a pointer or a lambda, to a templated function that accepts a `std::function`. I need to know what the argument and return types of the function objects are, so they are part of the template signature. I can make it work for a function accepting a function pointer, but not for one accepting a `std::function`. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong or if what I'm doing is actually possible. The code that fails is...

```
#include <functional>

template<typename RET, class ARG1>
auto setFuncPtr(RET fn(const ARG1&)) -> void
{
}

template<typename RET, class ARG1>
auto setStdFunc(const std::function<RET(const ARG1 &)> &fn) -> void
{
}

auto func(const int &i) -> int
{
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setFuncPtr(func); //< all good
    setStdFunc(func); //< compilation fails
    setStdFunc<int, int>(func); //< happy if I force the types
    setStdFunc([](const int &i) -> int { return i;}); //<  compilation fails
}
```

Clang 17 borks with the following...

```
<source>:21:5: error: no matching function for call to 'setStdFunc'
   21 |     setStdFunc(func); //< compilation fails
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
<source>:9:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'std::function<RET (const ARG1 &)>' against 'auto (const int &) -> int'
    9 | auto setStdFunc(const std::function<RET(const ARG1 &)> &fn) -> void
      |      ^
<source>:23:5: error: no matching function for call to 'setStdFunc'
   23 |     setStdFunc([](const int &i) -> int { return i;}); //<  compilation fails
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
<source>:9:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'std::function<RET (const ARG1 &)>' against '(lambda at <source>:23:16)'
    9 | auto setStdFunc(const std::function<RET(const ARG1 &)> &fn) -> void
      |      ^
2 errors generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/Pf1nzcEr7)

Comment: Why are you expecting type deduction here? Type deduction can happen only if there is no conversion! Here you have conversion from function pointer to `std::function` so conversion is required.

Comment: Both `func` and the lambda are not actually a `std::function` (althought they can be converted to one).

Comment: Thanks. So I'm asking for magic because of the type conversion that is needed before deduction can happen. I can't provide overloads for the argument and return types because I don't know what they will be, so explicit argument specification will be needed.

Comment: @brunobignose Do you need the return and argument types inside your function?  A simple template like `template <typename Func> void use_function(Func func) { func(); }` is all that is needed if you just want to pass around a function object and use it.  It's even trivial to get the return type of `Func` if needed.  Getting the parameters is harder but doable.

Comment: and if you do need the types, there are ways to figure them out, e.g. via a function trait class template. There are  multiple SO questions on how to write those yourself.

Comment: @NathanOliver I need to know the types inside my function.

Comment: @WeijunZhou I was hoping to avoid meta programming it all myself. If only C++ had better introspection.

Comment: In the end I think I'll just used the function pointer version as any lambdas should have no captures, but I would need to force the conversion via explicit template arguments for lambdas. Which is ugly from a client perspective.

Comment: The conversion is as simple as adding a unary plus before the lambda. Re "if only C++ had better introspection." Then you need to wait till C++26 when we will have proper compile-time reflection.

Comment: I am today years old when I discovered that C++ has a unary + operator. Thanks!

Comment: @brunobignose Your question was closed or I'd try to take a look myself. However, if you're after a way to determine function argument types ("I need to know the types inside my function"), then see my fully documented solution here: https://github.com/HexadigmAdmin/FunctionTraits

Comment: @Larry Thanks for that. I'll have a play with it tomorrow. Looks like what I need and very cool.

Comment: @Larry Forgot to say thank you, it works perfectly for what I needed.

Comment: @brunobignose Np. Note that a module version will be available in the next release (for C++20 and later).